# Can I install my POP account on my EXCHANGE Server at work in Outlook 2007

Tags: windows, exchange, imap, pop3

At work I have EXCHANGE Server, so I am getting emails (Work related). 
I wanted to add my personal email (POP or IMAP) and get those emails too.

I am afraid that if I do that, my work can still have access to my personal emails? 
Can they see if I send or receive emails?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You should check with your employer's acceptable use policies related to **their** computers.  In many jurisdictions the employer is entitled to know what you do on their computers and networks.  Setting Exchange up with your personal email account could get you fired.

Answer (score 1):

> I am afraid that if i do that, my work can still have access to my personal emails? and they will see if I send or receive emails.

Yes. They should be able to access your emails by going to \\hostname\C$\Documents and Settings\Alex\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook\YourPersonalEmails.pst and going through the personal store table.

If they're doing their bit then they probably have blocked the POP/SMTP and IMAP ports for workstations.

What's wrong with doing work at work?

EDIT: If you're going to go through with it, make sure you don't create the POP/IMAP account and specify the Exchange Inbox as the delivery location. Make a new PST.

Comment: +1, It's **their computer**, if you put your e-mail on it, it their right to look at it.

Comment: +1: It's the same with the phone: they have every right to listen to personal calls made through their phone system.

Comment: Actually, they do not. At least not in all countries. And in many it depends on either a written agreement or 'good employer/good employeemanship`. (In other words, a phone call home with "Honey, did I turn off the lights?" is allowed and they are not allowed to listen in. And you are not allowed to abuse that and make thousands of long distance calls).